# Trying to restore Time Machine. Lost boot disk

Tags: time-machine, backup, disk-utility, restore

I just bought a new Macbook Air after giving mine to my wife.  Before gifting the old laptop I created a Time Machine backup.

Now that I have my new MBAir, I went into Apple+R and chose to restore a Time Machine Backup.  Chose my backup, chose the Macintosh HD as the destination drive.  It failed.

Now, subsequent attempts have not shown Macintosh HD as a choice for restoration destination. It is also not a choice when trying to choose a start up disk.

However it does show up in Disk Utility.

Boot attempts without holding Apple+R take me to the same OSX Utilities Page.

It seems that I lost my Macintosh HD....

What should I do?

Comment: You'll have to do an Internet Recovery now, then do what you should have in the first place - Migrate. You'll be given the opportunity at the 'set up a new machine' introduction.

Comment: I am not able to choose the Macintosh HD as the destination for the recovery.

Comment: Format it in Disk Utility - GUID, HFS Extended, Journaled. Don't mess about with Recovery from Time Machine to dissimilar hardware, that's not what it was made for. Use Migrate.

Comment: It does not give me the option to format the Macintosh HD, only to format the recovery partition.  @Tetsujin the only place that i can even see ANY mention of Macintosh HD is in Disk Utility.  Other than that i would wonder if it was even attached any more.  I am ready to do ANYTHING.  the computer is brand new, i risk no information loss.  I will start from Absolute zero.  Suggestions?

Comment: At this point I'd be making an appointment at the Genius Bar. I'm not sure what else, if you can't even see the drive to format/install. Take the Time Machine with you & tell them what you did, what happened. They'll likely do the migrate for you as well. They're nice like that. Wish you luck :)

Comment: I took the computer back to the store.  It was only purchased 2 days ago.  They traded it out straight away.  Sorry i do not have a "technical" solution for resolution.  Thanks to everyone who tried.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted anyway - that's the most important thing :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how old the original MBA is compared to the new one, you probably won't be able to do a bare metal restore.

What you can do, is do a fresh OS install (if not done already) and "Migrate Your Settings" from the Time Machine Backup.